# Updating Qt Scene Graph in PyQt

Tags: qt, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I've been run the [Qt scenegraph tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-customgeometry-example.html) in PyQt5.  The good news is that I'm getting the bezier curve, as promised. Even better, when I resize the window, a new bezier curve is added to match the new window size.  The problem is that the old bezier curve is still there.  How do I get Qt to only draw the most recent geometry?

Here is my port of the drawing code from the tutorial

```
def updatePaintNode(self, oldNode, _):
    if not oldNode:
        node = QSGGeometryNode()
        geometry = QSGGeometry(QSGGeometry.defaultAttributes_Point2D(),
                               self._segment_count)
        geometry.setLineWidth(2)
        geometry.setDrawingMode(QSGGeometry.DrawLineStrip)
        node.setGeometry(geometry)
        node.setFlag(QSGNode.OwnsGeometry)
        material = QSGFlatColorMaterial()
        material.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
        node.setMaterial(material)
        node.setFlag(QSGNode.OwnsMaterial)
    else:
        node = oldNode
        geometry = node.geometry()
        geometry.allocate(self._segment_count)

    vertices = geometry.vertexDataAsPoint2D()

    for i in range(self._segment_count):
        t = float(i)/(self._segment_count-1)
        invt = 1-t

        pos = invt * invt * invt * self._p1 \
              + 3 * invt * invt * t * self._p2 \
              + 3 * invt * t * t * self._p3 \
              + t * t * t * self._p4 \


        x = pos.x() * self.width()
        y = pos.y() * self.height()

        vertices[i].set(x, y)

    node.markDirty(QSGNode.DirtyGeometry)

    return node
```

Comment: Don't you check - if `oldNode` is null after resizing?

Comment: @folibis The only place that I'm checking for null on oldNode is in line two of the above.  Is there a separate handler that I'm supposed to be implementing for resizes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is the best answer, but I stumbled into a work around.  I made the geometry node a child of a more general node and that seemed to fix the problem.  The first conditional now looks like:

```
    if not oldNode:
        node3 = QSGGeometryNode()
        node = QSGNode()
        node.appendChildNode(node3)

        geometry = QSGGeometry(QSGGeometry.defaultAttributes_Point2D(), self._segment_count)
        geometry.setLineWidth(2)
        geometry.setDrawingMode(QSGGeometry.DrawLineStrip)
        node3.setGeometry(geometry)
        node3.setFlag(QSGNode.OwnsGeometry)
        material = QSGFlatColorMaterial()
        material.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
        node3.setMaterial(material)
        node3.setFlag(QSGNode.OwnsMaterial)
    else:
        node = oldNode
        geometry = node.firstChild().geometry()
        geometry.allocate(self._segment_count)
```

Since I'm still not sure what I'm doing or *why* this worked, I'm not accepting this answer quite yet.  If someone who knows what they're doing wants to provide a better answer, I'd love to accept it.  However, I also wanted to document my own solution in case someone else is having this problem.